# JPA @OneToMany - Set vs List - Not able to delete one child entity from bidirectional association when using Set

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

Not able to delete child entity from OneToMany association if `Set` is used. Everything works fine if I use `List` instead of `Set`

Post.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Comment> comments;

public void addComment(Comment comment) {
    if (comments == null) {
        comments = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    comment.setPost(this);
    comments.add(comment);
}

public void removeComment(Comment comment) {
    if (comments == null || comments.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    comments.remove(comment);
    comment.setPost(null);
}
```

Comment.java

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include
private Post post;
```

Code for sample application is available on [Github](https://github.com/sudhirtumati/jpa-1toN-set)

- `master` branch is using `Set` and test case fails
- `list` branch is using 'List` and test case passes

Not sure whether I am making any mistake. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Your test asserts on the size of `Post.comments`. It is also `@Transactional`, meaning `postRepository.getOne()` returns the **exact same instance** of `Post` that you already have in the persistence context. This means `dbPost == post`, and so your problem has nothing to do with JPA, it is purely a Java problem.

Try putting a breakpoint at the `comments.remove(comment)` line. What you'll likely see is that it returns `false` for the `Set` version. That's because `hashCode/equals` is not implemented correctly. Try using `comments.removeIf(element -> element.getId().equals(comment.getId())` instead to see if the problem goes away.

(As a side note: there are multiple ways `equals/hashCode` can be implemented for JPA entities, but as a rule of thumb, making it compare a referenced entity is not a good idea, especially when that referenced entity is supposed to be lazily fetched).

EDIT:

The reason why the code works for `List`, and fails for `Set` is that:

- a `List` doesn't use `hashCode` at all,
- while looking up elements, a `HashSet` uses the `hashCode` value before `equals` to determine potential equality
- the `hashCode` of an element already in the `HashSet` is **not** recalculated automatically when that element is updated.

In the test, when you add `Comment`s to the `Post`, the `hashCode` of each comment is calculated based on the `Post.id` being `null`. However, as soon as you call `entityManager.flush()`, `Post.id` becomes non-null, and the `hashCode` of the `Comment` you're trying to remove changes. Hence, `remove` cannot find an element in the `Set` with the same (original) `hashCode` as the (newly calculated) `hashCode` for the `comment` passed as the parameter. **This is desipte the fact that `equals` would have returned `true` for one of the elements**. A `List` does not have this problem, because all it ever uses for element comparison is `equals`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I am debugging the issue, I did observe that the issue is due to object equality being false. But I am not sure why same code works when I replace `Set` with `List`. Coming to `equals/hashcode` implementation, I would prefer to just use `@Id` field. But as I am using UUID  identifier, I am not able to save a `post` with multiple `comments` (ID remains `null` until the object is persisted so only one comment is being saved)

Comment: Good answer, I also think the same